# Using ternary operator in component.html [Angular]

Tags: angular

I want to use ternary operator directly in ***value*** of input field

```
<div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="make" placeholder="make" />
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model" placeholder="model" />
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="miles" value="using ternary here.." />
  </div>
  <div *ngFor="let car of cars">
    We have a {{ car.make }} {{ car.model }} with a mileage of {{ car.miles }}
  </div>
</div>

<button (click)="addCar()">add Car</button>
```

How can I use ternary in field named **miles**?

Comment: Don't use `value` and `ngModel`. `ngModel` is sort of an Angular-managed alternative to `value`. Do you want to set an initial value using the ternary operator? Then maybe do so in the `component.ts` where you initialize `miles`.

Comment: I would also suggest that the value of the thing and the presentation of the thing should be separate (I'm guessing the reason you want to use a ternary is that you want to show a different string in the div under some circumstances). 
Instead of changing the value, use a `pipe` to _use_ the value and translate it to the string representation you need. So then the proper location for the ternary is the pipe.

Comment: I understand, thank you for advice Clashsoft

Comment: how can I use that (pipe) ?

Comment: instead of `{{ car.miles }}` you'd write `{{ car.miles | myPipe }}`. Have a look at the docs if you want to go that way :) https://angular.io/guide/pipes